# Get all opened Excel-documents

Tags: c#, excel

I need create xls-file with own data. But file may already be created, and opened by user.

(1) If file not exist:
new ApplicationClass()
Workbooks.Add()
SaveAs()...

(2) If file exist and not opened: not problem - goto (1)

(3) if the file exists and is opened by the user: need find it workbook and reform data of worksheet.

With (3) I have problem. Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application") finded only active workbook.

Comment: Marshal.BindToMoniker helped me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know is late to answer you, but may be useful to someone else.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp;

oExcelApp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WB in oExcelApp.Workbooks) {
   MessageBox.Show(WB.FullName);
}

oExcelApp = null;
```