# c# Get all opened Excel documents

Tags: c#, excel

I found some code samples in stuckoverflow
here : [Get all opened Excel-documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669392/get-all-opened-excel-documents)

and used it for this:

```
  foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook WB in oExcelApp.Workbooks)
            {
                if(WB.Name == filename)
                xlwkbook = WB;
            }
```

i opened 3 excel files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftfIc.png)

and every time that i open them and execute the code then i have in the loop (in oExcelApp.Workbooks) different numbers of excels.

sometime i have only - 2production.xlsm

sometime i have - 2production.xlsm and europe.xlsm

sometime all of them

every time something else.

why i dont get all of them every time???

pleas help.